# Rigorously proof of the following

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to know how to prove these, I have formally proven them not sure I did a good job:

1. $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) = \varnothing$
2. $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \setminus B) = B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, suppose $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A\setminus B)$. Then since $x \in A \cap B$, $x \in B$. But since $x \in A \setminus B$, $x \not \in B$. Thus our supposition lead to a contradiction, i.e. there is no $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B)$, so $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) = \varnothing$.

The other one is somewhat similar. As the comment points out, you have to show that $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \setminus B)\subset B$ and also that $B \subset (A \cup B) \setminus (A \setminus B)$.

The proof of those two claims is not too bad. If you want to prove $X \subset Y$, start with something in $X$ and show that it must also be in $Y$, using the definitions of $X$ and $Y$. Here you'll have to use the definition of the union and set difference, they're your only tools.

Also, when first working with elementary set theory, it's often best to try to draw a Venn diagram. While not a "formal proof," they're often helpful in providing intuition for the direction the proof should take.

Comment: Well, technically not so similar, for someone who is not used to formal proofs. For one thing, the first problem can be done by checking (as you did) just the half "$(A\cap B)\cap(A\setminus B)\subseteq \emptyset$". However, for the second one there is no way around it: one **must** prove both inclusions.

Comment: I guess that's a good point. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it “algebraically”. If you set $X=A\cup B$, then you can define $U^c=X\setminus U$, for any $U\subseteq X$. Then $U\setminus V=U\cap V^c$, for $U,V\subseteq X$. Then
$$
(A\cap B)\cap (A\setminus B)=
A\cap B\cap A\cap B^c=
A\cap B\cap B^c=A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset
$$
because $B\cap B^c=\emptyset$.

Using De Morgan's laws and $(B^c)^c=B$,
$$
(A\cup B)\setminus(A\setminus B)=
(A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B^c)^c=
(A\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B)=
(A\cap A^c)\cup B=\emptyset\cup B=B
$$